# Adb command to get tablet date format

Tags: android, shell, date, cmd

In an android application, I am trying to get the tablet's date format (ie. dd/mm/yyyy or mm.dd.yyyy) using adb shell command

-"*adb shell settings get system date_format*"

However, this command seems to work only for device with API 23 level. For level less than 23, this command gives no result. Is there a command to get date format for devices with API level less than 23?

Comment: I tested here in a Android 4.4.4 Samsung phone and this command works fine... So, maybe, it is not related to API version.

Answer (score 0):

I think that setting is null (or empty) because is not set.

I tested here in two different devices with Android MM and Android KitKat (4.4.4).

In both devices, the command `adb shell settings get system date_format` works normally.

Checking this [question](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3973), Google suggested to use:

```
android.text.DateFormat.getDateFormat()
```

> Please use android.text.DateFormat.getDateFormat() instead of looking at the setting 
>   directly, which will work whether or not the setting is set.

So, if possible, try to get the data format in the proper way (and not via adb command).

Comment: I am not able to import android.text.DateFormat.getDateFormat(). When i click on the auto import, java.text.DateFormat gets imported.

Comment: I think they are the same.. is not working with getDateFormat()?

Comment: Actually java.text.DateFormat does not have the function getDateFormat().